# XSL Call Template String param as group-by element value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Lets say I have the following `xsl:template` element:

```
<xsl:template name="acct-row-l3">
  <xsl:param name="category" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$category" group-by="concat(ACCT_3, '|', ACCT3_DESC)">
  . . .
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

and I want to change it to allow me to pass in an account level so that the `group-by="concat(ACCT_3, '|', ACCT3_DESC)"` portion of the template can by dynamic. something like this:

`group-by="concat($acct, '|', $acct-desc)"`

Is there are a way to do this?

Comment: The code looks a bit odd, you have `category` typed as a single `element()` node but then try to group that single element node by a string formed with a `concat()` call? I don't understand what kind of grouping that would achieve. As for variable references in the `concat` calll, well, that is of course possible but more mysterious in my view as it groups on a string value not even based on XPath selection related to the `$category`. Perhaps show us some input samples and how you want to group them and the whole approach is clearer. Perhaps you look for `xsl:evaluate` but that needs XSLT 3

Comment: And as with all things perhaps needing `xsl:evaluate`, the simple case of simply selecting a child element by name can usually expressed as a predicate comparing the node name `concat(*[local-name() = $acct], '|', *[local-name() = $acct-desc])`.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3 with function expressions (e.g. as supported in Saxon 10 all editions or Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 EE and PE) the cleanest approach might be to parameterize the `group-by` as a function:

```
<xsl:param name="group-by" as="function(item()) as item()*"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="..." group-by="$group-by(.)">...</xsl:for-each-group>
```

where you can then pass in e.g `<xsl:with-param name="group-by" select="function($c) { concat($c/foo, '|', $c/bar) }"/>` or `<xsl:with-param name="group-by" select="function($c) { concat($c/acc1, '|', $c/desc1) }"/>`.